# In Shiny, how can I change the formatting of the labels of a range slider?

Tags: css, r, shiny, rangeslider, ion-range-slider

Shiny makes use of the [ion-rangeslider](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/tree/master/inst/www/shared/ionrangeslider).

I'm trying to change the formatting of the labels of a range slider. In the code below, `.irs-single { color: black; background: transparent }` removes the default blue background of the label in the regular slider (top), but it has no effect on the labels of the range slider (bottom).

---

[image: shiny output]

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("test1",
              "Select a value:",
              min = 0,
              max = 50,
              value = 20),
  sliderInput("test2",
              "Select a range:",
              min = 0,
              max = 50,
              value = c(30, 40)),
  tags$style(type = "text/css",
             HTML(
               ".irs-single { color: black; background: transparent }")
             )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

I tried adding each of the following, directly targeting the range slider:

1. `.js-irs-1 .irs-single { color: black; background: transparent }`
2. `.js-irs-1 .irs-single.to { color: black; background: transparent }`
3. `.js-irs-1 .irs-single.from { color: black; background: transparent }`

But the rang slider's labels still come out with their default color, blue:

[image: shiny output]

---

Not that it's possible to, for instance, directly target the formatting of one of the range slider's buttons:

`.js-irs-1 .irs-slider.to { background: red }`

[image: shiny output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(shiny)

css <- "
.irs-from, .irs-to { color: black; background: transparent }
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("test1",
              "Select a value:",
              min = 0,
              max = 50,
              value = 20),
  sliderInput("test2",
              "Select a range:",
              min = 0,
              max = 50,
              value = c(30, 40)),
  tags$style(type = "text/css", HTML(css))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: But your label 20 in the first bar is blue.

Answer (score 2):

In `tags$style` you need to change the `.irs-single` to `.irs-from, .irs-to, .irs-single` in order to affect the range slider in both sliders.

So using your code with changing `.irs-single` to `.irs-from, .irs-to, .irs-single`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("test1",
              "Select a value:",
              min = 0,
              max = 50,
              value = 20),
  sliderInput("test2",
              "Select a range:",
              min = 0,
              max = 50,
              value = c(30, 40)),
  tags$style(type = "text/css",
             HTML(
               ".irs-from, .irs-to, .irs-single { color: black; background: transparent }")
             )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Produces this transparent sliders range:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't target the labels.

Comment: I've edited my answer. E.g. you do not need to define new vector, i.e., `css <- "
.irs-from, .irs-to { color: black; background: transparent }
"`. See my edit.

Comment: Obviously it is not necessary to define the css outside the UI. But I prefer ^^